# inplace string reverse using std::async

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been trying to reverse a string using std::async (or std::thread) inplace but have not been able to find a successful algorithm.

```
void reverse(char* x, char* y)
{
    while (x < y)
    {
        char temp = *x;
        *x = *y;
        *y = temp;
        x++;
        y--;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int numthreads = 2;
    char input[] = "abcdef";
    size_t size = strlen(input);
    size_t substrsize = 0;

    substrsize = size / numthreads;

    char* end = &input[strlen(input) - 1];
    char* begin = &(input[size-substrsize]);

    for (int i = 0; i < numthreads; i++)
    {
        std::async(std::launch::async, reverse, begin, end);
        end = begin -1; 
        begin = begin-substrsize;
    }

    cout << input << endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

For simplicity, I have assumed that the input can be divided in substrings of equal sizes (ie; size % numthreads is assumed to be zero)

However, with above, what I get in output is:

```
cbafed
```

I understand this output because abc and def are reversed in place. However, the correct output would be **fedcba**.

Is it possible to extend this code to achieve the desired output? I tried to store the returned future in a vector (by moving) and then call get on it but it did not help (probably because the function returns void)

Please give some hints or suggestions to make it work correctly.
Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried without async?

Comment: @GManNickG I tried with array of std::thread but I get the same result.

Comment: I think he means chuck the threading and watch your code fail when run sequentially. My addition would be "Then march through the code with a debugger and tweak the code until it works without threading. Once you have that working, add the threads back in and watch the threads simultaneously stomp over the array until you add in mutexes or some such to prevent destruction."

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm divides the source string into two substrings, the first of which is "def". Your "reverse" algorithm swaps "d" and "f", inc/decs the pointers to point to "e" and swaps "e" with itself.

The result is two reversed substrings:

```
abc  def
```

becomes

```
cba  fed
```

You need to change your reverse algorithm to take 3 inputs:

```
void reverse(char* begin, const char* const end, char* back) {
    while (begin != end) {
        std::swap(*(begin++), *(--back));
    }
}
```

And then you need to call it with sub-ranges of your string:

```
size_t subtrlen = 2;
reverse(input + 0, input + substrlen, input + sizeof(input) - 1);
reverse(input + substrlen, input + 3, input + sizeof(input) - 1 - substrlen);
```

Demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char* begin, const char* const end, char* back) {
    while (begin != end) {
        std::swap(*(begin++), *(--back));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char input[] = "abcdef";
    size_t len = strlen(input);
    size_t substrlen = 2;
    std::cout << input << std::endl;    
    reverse(input, input + substrlen, input + len);
    reverse(input + substrlen, input + substrlen, input + len - substrlen);
    std::cout << input << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/gGjB9D

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not wrong you are trying to reverse the string a multi-thread way. So you need an algorithm which performs in a multithread context.

This is a simple solution I can propose for you.

The algorithm (funciton) multithread is

```
void reverse_str_mt(char* str,
                const size_t len,
                const size_t id_thread,
                const size_t max_num_threads) {
  // Some assertion on input parameters
  assert(str != nullptr);
  assert(max_num_threads != 0);

  // In case the num of threads is greater than the len of the string
  if (id_thread > len) {
    assert(max_num_threads > len);
    return;
  }

  // Swap operation
  for (size_t i = id_thread; i <= len / 2; i += max_num_threads) {
    std::swap(str[i], str[len - i - 1]);
  }
}
```

And you can operate on a string like this way:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  static constexpr size_t NUM_THREADS = 10;
  char str[] = "123456";
  const auto len = strlen(str);

  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
    threads.emplace_back(reverse_str_mt, str, len , i, NUM_THREADS);
  }

  // Join threads
  for (auto& t : threads) {
    t.join();
  }

  // Print the result
  std::cout << str << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Just for completeness the headers you should include are:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>
```

That is a runnable [example](http://ideone.com/12zgp4).

Comment: Yes, I was looking to reverse using multithreading. After my initial post, I could do it using async, but had to make copies of each substring to be reversed which is not as efficient. Just a thought: You could swap without for loop:  `if (id_thread < len / 2) {
    std::swap(str[id_thread], str[len - id_thread - 1]);
  }`

Comment: @user2930006 The *for loop* is necessary. Your solution will work only when the number of threads is greater then the string's length.